# Clickable and rotatable models using Android Studio and ARToolkit by using ARNativeOSG sample project

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

Can the 3D models used with the markers be made click-able and rotatable using Android Studio and ARToolkit ? Basically in the AR android application I want to implement this functionality on the 3D models as well.

Problem is: I have downloaded Android SDK for ARToolkit from ARToolkit.org and in it there is a sample app named ARNativeOSG which show a model while scanning a marker available in same SDK.but I want to rotate that model which is a plane by 360 degree by using touch coordinates.So my question is that how to rotate it and where is that model is used? I am using Android Studio with JDK 1.7.

and can i make my own model in it and of which format?

Comment: Possible duplicate [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119583/clickable-and-rotatable-models-using-xcode-and-artoolkit). If you are one person operating two accounts, please desist - we prefer people to stick to one online identity around here.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: no that is not my account https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119583/clickable-and-rotatable-models-using-xcode-and-artoolkit and not my question. @halfer

Comment: OK. It's the same question, and the other author edited your question as if they knew what to ask, but alright. It seems a bit vague at present, would you edit it to provide more detail?